# How can I build vim with just python 3 support?

Tags: linux, installing, vimscript-python, linux-arch

I'm on Arch, and recently the `vim-python3` and `gvim-python3` packages were removed, so I'm working on building vim from source such that the `:python` command will act as `python3`. Specifically, I'm doing this so that the `vim-jedi` package will work properly. I tried changing the

```
--enable-pythoninterp=dynamic
```

flag in my `PKGBUILD` to

```
--disable-pythoninterp
```

but when I did `vim --version` after building and installing, it still showed

```
+python/dyn
```

Also, doing

```
:python import sys;print(sys.version)
```

showed python 2 still. What do I need to change to have only python 3?

Comment: The exact same command works for me.

Comment: `:python command will act as python3` ... is that possible without mapping `:python` to `:python3`?

Comment: @muru: I'm not sure. Regardless, in order to get jedi-vim to work, I need python 3 to be the default version in vim, and I'm not sure how to make that happen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to x33a on the Arch forums, I was able to solve my problem. (https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1596987#p1596987)

I changed the python 3 flag from

```
--enable-python3interp=dyanmic
```

to

```
--enable-python3interp
```

This resulted in only python 3 being available.

Answer (score 5):

The problem was not in Vim's default Python interpreter.

The real root of the problem is that the last version of `jedi-vim` (0.7.0) was released in 2013 and did not work well with Python 3.

Since then Python 3 support in `jedi-vim` has been improved a lot.
We (Arch users) asked `jedi-vim` to make a new release. `0.8.0` has been released and now it is in the Arch repo. Please remove the hacked Vim and update Arch. `jedi-vim` is supposed to work well now.

Moral of this story: do not try to add workarounds over workarounds. Try to find the *real* root of the issue and fix that. Work with upstream more actively. Do not be afraid to ask.

Comment: ["Do not be afraid to ask"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do+not+be+afraid+to%2Cdo+not+afraid+to%2Cdo+not+fear+to&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cdo%20not%20be%20afraid%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BDo%20not%20be%20afraid%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdo%20not%20be%20afraid%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDo%20not%20Be%20Afraid%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cdo%20not%20fear%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdo%20not%20fear%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDo%20not%20fear%20to%3B%2Cc0) is the correct phrasing here.