# How to add python3 interface to vim?

Tags: plugin-ultisnips, macos, python

I want to use Ultisnips and get the following error:

```
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: py3 import vim
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing /Users/Me/.vim/plugged/ultisnips/autoload/UltiSnips.vim:
line    8:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: py3 from UltiSnips import UltiSnips_Manager
```

I think this correlates to the fact that I get `0` as the output when running `:echo has('python3')`. How can I fix this issue?

My operations system is macOS Big Sur.

I have tried several times to reinstall vim with home-brew but I still get [image]

when executing `vim --version`. Any idea how one can fix this on MacOS?

Comment: See [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/18433) (looks like the homebrew version includes python3 support) and [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6164) or [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/17433)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: @statox I don't have a `./configure` file

Comment: The `configure` file is present in the git repository of vim you'll have to use if you build vim from sources.

Comment: vim installed with homebrew should have python3 support. Once you have installed it, check it is the homebrew version you are invoking with `which vim`. I wonder if, judging by your duplicate question, you are still invoking system vim.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's some issue with your Homebrew setup or with the Vim build in your Homebrew.

When you type `which vim` does it show you `/usr/local/bin/vim`? That's the one from Homebrew. If it doesn't and lists `/usr/bin/vim` instead, does `echo $PATH` list `/usr/local/bin` somewhere at the start?

If you try `/usr/local/bin/vim --version` does it show support for `+python3` (or ``+python3/dyn`) as expected?

If it looks like your Homebrew setup might be broken, try the `brew doctor` command to try to diagnose and/or repair it. See also [Homebrew Common Issues](https://docs.brew.sh/Common-Issues#other-local-issues) for instructions on how to completely reinstall it, if needed.

Comment: yes, I this must be the issue, I'm getting `/usr/bin/vim`, brew doctor doesn't give any information concerning this however.

Comment: Maybe try reinstalling Homebrew? I believe it will try to modify your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zshrc` to add `/usr/local/bin` to the `$PATH`, but I don't recall which file exactly it will change and how... That's probably where the problem with your setup is.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, my vim was apparently not installed through brew.
Running `brew install vim` solved the issue for me. VIM got installed through brew and python3 support works flawless now.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!